# How to read .dss (audio file) metadata with python

Tags: python, audio, metadata, dictation

The .dss (or .ds2) file format is used for dictation devices e.g. by Philips or Olympus and stores metadata on the dictation file in addition to the audio information.

Is there a way to somehow readout this metadata by using a simple python routine?

One idea was to read out the file in binary format, yet I could not do it by myself.

Help anyone :-) ?

Sample file (short dictation with metadata) available here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g5uk22prkqht372/TH10094.DSS?dl=0

In the sample file there are the metadata "Sofort", "Heartbeat" and "WGB", which needs to be looked for. Can't find them though.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521525/reading-metadata-with-python

Comment: Thanks, but the description in the link doesn't work on linux systems, where I need the readout for.

Comment: sorry, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49804736/read-dss-database-file-in-python and https://github.com/gyanz/pydsstools